# Difference in operators (lmer)

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, modeling

I'm building linear mixed effect models with lmer. At first I was writing the formula like this:

```
model_1 <- lmer(response ~ A + B + C + A:B + A:C + B:C + A:B:C + (1|Subject), data)
```

But I have been adding more terms to the fixed-effects parts so I tried this way I saw:

```
model_2 <- lmer(response ~ A*B*C + (1|Subject), data)
```

As I had read that using * would provide the same result as combining + and :, but I have been getting different models and also different results.

Could anyone point me to some resources where I can learn how to do this properly? Or explain the differences between the two models. Thanks!

PS: It's my first time usin SE, I tried searching for something similar but could not find it. Sorry if it has been asked before.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some sample results, e.g. using summary(), to facilitate comparison.